# How to display an image?

Tags: reactjs

I can not display the image, I do

```
const imgUrl = companyList.find(i => i.id === items.companyId).imgUrl;
```

[image]

And after creating the block, the desired picture is displayed, but it is worth updating the page, as ...

[image]

Everything is normally added to the database and should work ...
In my other file, I use the exact same method and everything works, but for some reason there isn’t ...

```
const getInvoiceList = () => {
    return invoiceList.map(items => {
        const imgUrl = companyList.find(i => i.id === items.companyId).imgUrl;
        return (
                <div key={items.id} className="invoice__card">
                    <div className="card__data">
                        <p>{items.invoice}</p>
                        <i onClick={() => onVisibleDetails(items.id)}><FiMoreHorizontal /></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card__body">

                    <div className="invoice__order">
                            <p>Оплатил</p>
                            <img src={imgUrl} alt="logo" />
                        </div>

                        <div className="invoice__order">
                            <h3>$2.400</h3>
                            <p>Сумма</p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="invoice__date">
                            <h3>30.01.2020</h3>
                            <p>Дата оплаты</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
    });
};

<div className="invoice__card-wrapper">
    {invoiceList.length !== 0 ? getInvoiceList() : "Nety"}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your data is either incomplete, or the structure isn't matching up with the way you're trying to access it. The error `Cannot read property "imgUrl"` is occurring because your `find()` method call is not finding an object, so the `imgUrl` property isn't defined.

This will keep the error from occurring:

```js
const imgUrl = (companyList.find(i => i.id === items.companyId) || {}).imgUrl;
```

If you want to add more info about where the `companyList` is coming from, we might be able to get closer to an answer.

Comment: What does || {}?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/jHQCr7j.png?1
https://i.imgur.com/ApWQghs.png?1


Here is my database, everything is right ...